# Avoiding unnecessary readings - AngularFirestore

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have a schedule component in Angular, where every time the user goes opens the component, a subscription to one document starts. Is that going to going to count as a reading?

**For example**
The user goes in to the component one time: 1 read
The user goes out and into the same component again: 1 read again

Am I correct to assume that on every init, a new reading is progress? And if so, how can I avoid this?

Comment: Sounds like it, without seeing your code it's hard to see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do API calls from inside a UI component. Have a service file that holds the fetched data once. The UI component will get the data from your local service and won't need to invoke a firebase call.

Comment: `useMemo` sounds like you're talking about react, OP tagged Angular.

Comment: Okay, but if I should I then return an Observable from the service file? Or would that count as a read too?

Comment: Why you need an Observable? if you need the data to be synced with firestore than you must do a firebase call for each update.
If you don't need the data to be synced live you can save the fetched data inside a Service property.
Then use that property in your component.

Comment: Understandable. Thanks for the answer!